# Call to undefined method MongoDB\Driver\ReadConcern::isDefault()

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

[I really don't know what the problem is!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeeOb.png)

```
class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    public function store(request $request)
    {

        $reg = Register::all();
        var_dump($reg);
```

and Register is

```
class Register extends Moloquent
{

    protected $connection='mongodb';
    protected $collection='registers';

}
```

Comment: Check this issue on github: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library/issues/412

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by setting my composer.json like this:

```
{
  "require": {
    "mongodb/mongodb": "1.1.2"
  }
}
```

Then run `composer update`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a method that was taken from latest version of the library `mongodb/mongodb`.

This method is still available in the version: `1.1.2`.

To resolve this issue temporarily, update the `composer.lock` file by replacing the following content:

```
{
    "name": "mongodb/mongodb",
    "version": "1.1.2",
    "source": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library.git",
        "reference": "a307dd60e71e1291c60927ea4f3a1905146063f5"
    },
    "dist": {
        "type": "zip",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mongodb/mongo-php-library/zipball/a307dd60e71e1291c60927ea4f3a1905146063f5",
        "reference": "a307dd60e71e1291c60927ea4f3a1905146063f5",
        "shasum": ""
    },
    "require": {
        "ext-mongodb": "^1.2.0",
        "php": ">=5.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^4.8"
    },
    "type": "library",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "MongoDB\\": "src/"
        },
        "files": [
            "src/functions.php"
        ]
    },
    "notification-url": "https://packagist.org/downloads/",
    "license": [
        "Apache-2.0"
    ],
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Jeremy Mikola",
            "email": "jmikola@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "Hannes Magnusson",
            "email": "bjori@mongodb.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "Derick Rethans",
            "email": "github@derickrethans.nl"
        }
    ],
    "description": "MongoDB driver library",
    "homepage": "https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHPLIB",
    "keywords": [
        "database",
        "driver",
        "mongodb",
        "persistence"
    ],
    "time": "2017-02-16T18:40:32+00:00"
},
```

And run `composer install`