# Call to undefined method MongoDB\Driver\ReadConcern::isDefault() after composer update

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-5

After the composer update (composer update --no-scripts) i am getting below error :

```
FatalThrowableError Call to undefined method MongoDB\Driver\ReadConcern::isDefault()
```

I found the similar issue but i am not getting a proper solution. I checked [ReadConcern::isDefault](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library/issues/412) and [Called to Undefined Method ReadConcern::isDefault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47375336/call-to-undefined-method-mongodb-driver-readconcernisdefault)

When I execute `sudo apt install php-mongodb`, i got the following result:

```
php-mongodb is already the newest version (1.4.2-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).
```

On composer.json file, i have this :

```
"mongodb/mongodb": "^1.1.0",
```

On composer Update, on terminal i can see this:

```
Updating mongodb/mongodb (1.1.2 => 1.3.2): Loading from cache
```

Is there something with the versions of these.

What should i do now to resolve the issue, please suggest.

Comment: Running the "system" version of any language for your application is always bad news. There are version environment managers which have been around for years to counter this very problem. I suggest you try a `phpbrew` or similar instead of using a system package install. Then go through all those installs again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what was the issue but finally the issue got resolved. This worked for me:

I deleted the Laravel vendors directory:

```
rm -rf vendors/
```

Cleared the composer cache:

```
composer clearcache
```

Again composer install:

```
composer install --no-scripts
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had same problem.Following change worked for me.
Change the line 48 of league\oauth2-server\src\CryptKey.php as follows.

> if ($keyPermissionsCheck === false) {

Simply change true to false or comment the whole if block.

Best solution is update mongoDB to ~4.0
But if you can't update you can try that solution.